# Blogtrigger yielding HEAD 404 errors in Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've got a BlobTrigger that is setup as follows:

```cs
[FunctionName("TransformFile")]
public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("%container%/{name}", Connection = "storage")] Stream blobIn,
    [Blob("%container%-pdf/{name}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "storage")] Stream blobOut)
{
    //...
}
```

What is does it take the file from 1 container, mutate it and write it back to another container. I see that every call that's made to the blobtrigger shows a dependency exception call in Application Insights to the storage where the new blob is written to that logically does not exist at that point and I'm not sure why it makes these as it shouldn't matter to the Storage API whether or not the blob already exists for writing to it.

I could also write to the `blobOut` using the NuGet package as workaround, but that's not best practise. Or just ignore the exceptions as the function runs without issues, although with every call throwing the exception the logs become quite congested with useless exceptions.

I have the following NuGet packages in my project:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.0.4
Microsoft.NET.sdk.Functions 1.0.24
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add your code please ? nothing really we can see with the code you've posted so far

Comment: @Thomas for testing purposes I've published it from Visual Studio with literally the above bit code (nothing happens inside) and that still throws the exception in the logging

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop, do you click the Run button in azure portal -> azure function for your case? When I click the run button, it will throw 404 error in app insights. But it's no 404 error if just upload file to blob container, no click the run button.

Comment: @IvanYang no. I upload a file or files to the blob container and let the blob trigger from the function app do the rest.

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop, it's weird. But for your information, I use the latest version of the nuget package: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.0.6, Microsoft.NET.sdk.Functions 1.0.29, WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3

Comment: @IvanYang I've upgraded to `Microsoft.NET.sdk.Functions 1.0.29` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.0.6` with the same results

Comment: Also added `WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3` still with the same result

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try with my code, I have test it local, it will create the container `%container%-pdf` and upload the blob to the container.

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("%container%/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob,
            [Blob("%container%-pdf/{name}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudBlockBlob outputblob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            outputblob.UploadFromStreamAsync(myBlob);

        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but while I can get the function to work in my code above. `Application Insights` keeps registering a 404 HEAD dependency call for every call. Those exceptions make it look on the dashboard as if there's a huge issue while everything runs fine, while I don't see a reason why the binding would make them for `FileAccess.Write`